# Angular 6 Capturing child component value in parent using @Output()

Tags: angular

In my child component, on click of a button a process fires and returns a boolean. I need to capture this boolean in my parent component and enable/disable a button. I have never used `@Output()` before. I have created a sample to show the issue. In the dev tools I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.onclickValidateAndSave is not a function
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    //passing value to parent component thru event payload
    bSuccess: boolean = false;

    @Output()
    public clickValidateAndSave: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
   public onclickValidateAndSave() {
       this.clickValidateAndSave.emit(this.bSuccess);
      //not being logged
       console.log(this.bSuccess);
   }

    toggleSuccess() {
        this.bSuccess = !this.bSuccess;
    }
}
```

Here is child.component.html:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" 
                (click)="toggleSuccess()">
            Toggle Success
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    disableBtn: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
    handleClickOnChild(bSuccess) {
        this.disableBtn = !bSuccess
    }
}
```

and parent.component.html

```
<app-child (clickValidateAndSave)="handleClickOnChild($event)"></app-child>
<div class="row col-mg-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableBtn" ngDefaultControl name="name">
        Submit for Approval
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: try changing [(ngModel)]="clickValidateAndSave" to (clickValidateAndSave)="yourFunctionInParent()"

Comment: Amit, I made the suggested changes, there is no error, however, onclickValidateAndSave() never gets called and the button is always enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<app-child (clickValidateAndSave)="handleClickOnChild($event)" ></app-child>
<div class="row col-mg-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disableBtn"
            [(ngModel)]="clickValidateAndSave">
        Submit for Approval {{clickValidateAndSave}}
    </button>
</div>
```

and in parent js

```
 disableBtn = false;
 ...

 handleClickOnChild(bSuccess) {
     this.disableBtn = !bSuccess
 }
```

I write code from head so it can have some bugs

Comment: Where do we get value for bSuccess in parent js?

Comment: This is the right approach. The parent component must have a way of handling the child `@Output()` event.

Comment: @SilverFish the object/value send during event emit is set in parent teemplate in as `$event` - and template pass it to handler as first parameter.

Comment: now I get: ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: doesn't say line. It is coming from Vendor.js. This happens right when page loads/refreshes. Moreover, the button Submit for Approval is enabled at all time right when it loaded

Comment: @SilverFish ask separate question for this

Answer (score 1):

You mixed everything up a little bit, you need to use `emit(value)` method on `@Output` field in child component, and that value would be passed into the method in parent component with which you subscribed on particular `Output` of child. For example take a look [on this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-x4drgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fchild.component.ts) (look in "example" folder):

---

Here we trigger event in child component:

```
toggleSuccess() {
    this.clickValidateAndSave.emit(this.bSuccess = !this.bSuccess);
}
```

Here we subscribe on that event in parent component:

```
<app-child (clickValidateAndSave)="onClickValidateAndSave($event)"></app-child>
```

And here that method in parent with which we subscribed on child event:

```
onClickValidateAndSave(value: boolean) {
    this.buttonDisabled = value;
}
```

Pay attention that we can access `Output` event value via parameters.
Hope that helps.